# Find Whole word & Replace on Word Document

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel VBA code to find and replace word in Word Document.
I have a list of word to find in excel (column 1) and replace it with other word found in column 2.
But my problem is I only need to find the match whole word e.g. hap I only need to replace all words hap but on my code it also replace the word like Chapter.

I already tried to true the `MatchWholeWord` but still changing if the word is part of the other word.

```
wDoc.Application.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    wDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    For i = 2 To lr

        With wDoc.Application.Selection.Find

            .Text = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
            .Replacement.Text = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False

        End With

        wDoc.Application.Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Next
```

I want my results to find the exact match word and not the part of the word. Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you running Excel VBA code in Word? What are you aiming to achieve?

Comment: I tried your code in Word. It's only replacing the correct word.

Comment: @AAA I'm not running Excel VBA in Word, I'm running it on excel but I'm manipulating the Word document

Comment: For your replacement text, try using Value2 instead of Value.  You can also replace Selection.Find with ActiveDocument.Content.Find.